# Mcdonald's Sausage patty - brined?

Tags: pork, brining, sausages

I've been trying make my own sausage patty recipe for some time now. But recently, after eating a Sausage McMuffin, I wondered if Mcdonald's uses brined pork sausage for their sausage patties.

After all -- I think sausages are really brined, originally?

So the question is. Is the pork in sausage patties brined and/or cured? If so, does the brining occure before grinding the meat or after?

Comment: Brine a patty seems odd to me.

Comment: I am not sure anyone can honestly answer what McD's do in their proprietary process, and I will put this as a comment only as it is opinion, not fact.The massive amounts of salt (830 mg in a small sandwich much of which would be in the small portion of meat), with both dextrose and sugar in the sausage would be a general indication a brine or cure was used on poor quality meat to help soften it and make it seem edible. I cannot say this is something I would want to duplicate, but if you do, after grinding would be faster acting, before may aid in grinding.

Comment: I was also thinking that brining after grinding (as a patty, I guess) would reorganize the protein binding of meat cells, thereby creating the singular, juicy patty that bites-off like a bratwurst.